# Firebase phone number authentication code getting null

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

When I uninstall and reinstall the android app, the verification code and message are getting perfectly, but when I restart the application and send mobile number for verification I don't get any message or verification code. And also same thing on resend button.

I'm not getting any error message.

My code is....

```
   private void sendVerificationCode(String mobile) {
    PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
             mobile,
            60,
            TimeUnit.SECONDS,
            TaskExecutors.MAIN_THREAD,
            mCallbacks);
   }



  private PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks mCallbacks = 
  new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {
    @Override
    public void onVerificationCompleted(PhoneAuthCredential 
     phoneAuthCredential) {
        String code = phoneAuthCredential.getSmsCode();

        Log.i("sad","codeis========"+code);
        if (code != null) {
            edtphoneemail.setText(code);
            verifyVerificationCode(code);
        }
     }

    @Override
    public void onVerificationFailed(FirebaseException e) {
        //Toast.makeText(VerifyPhoneActivity.this, e.getMessage(), 
         Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.i("a","asdf==="+e);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCodeSent(String s, PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken 
    forceResendingToken) {
        super.onCodeSent(s, forceResendingToken);
        Log.i("sadf","sdf=====code sucess fiully"+s);
        //storing the verification id that is sent to the user
        mVerificationId = s;
        mResendToken = forceResendingToken;
    }
  };


   private void verifyVerificationCode(String code) {
    //creating the credential
    PhoneAuthCredential credential = 
    PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(mVerificationId, code);

    Log.i("sdf","mVerificationId===="+code);
    //signing the user
    signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential);
  }


 private void signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(PhoneAuthCredential credential) 
 {
    mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult> 
  () {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                      Log.i("sadf","sdf=====code sucess fiully");

                    } else {                    
                    String message = "Somthing is wrong, we will fix it 
                    soon...";

        if (task.getException() instanceof 
                    FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {
                            message = "Invalid code entered...";
                        }

                        Snackbar snackbar = 
                        Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.parent), message, 
                       Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
                        snackbar.setAction("Dismiss", new 
                    View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {

                            }
                        });
                        snackbar.show();
                    }
                }
            });
     }

   private void resendVerificationCode(String phoneNumber,
                    PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken token) {
            PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
            phoneNumber,        // Phone number to verify
            60,                 // Timeout duration
            TimeUnit.SECONDS,   // Unit of timeout
            this,               // Activity (for callback binding)
            mCallbacks,         // OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks
            token);             // ForceResendingToken from callbacks
       }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't get OTP every time. Firebase automatically detects the SIM card in the mobile and the phone number associated with it. If it was successful, then the authentication is automatically completed and you must sign in the user.

Answer (score 0):

I just change the sim card network type 4g to 2g and I get the OTP from firebase